# FreeBSD - Can one reinstall an older package from a cached txz file?

Tags: upgrade, freebsd, rollback

I need to revert to an older version of libreoffice on a FreeBSD-12.0p10 host.  The older versions are all in /var/cache/pkg/.  How do I revert to an older version?

Comment: Questions about the FreeBSD operating system should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ This is not a programming question. Please delete this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just `pkg add /full/path/to/package.txz`.